# Delphi: Alternative to JEDI Desktop Alert (balloon)

Tags: delphi, desktop, message, alert, balloon

Is there a good analogue/equivalent to **JEDI Desktop Alert** (a kind of a balloon in the right bottom corner of a desktop)?

`Balloon hint` cannot be showed like a stack (a new hint is on the top of others), but JEDI Desktop Alert can do it.

*May be some one knows, why does a show event of that component fire twice instead of once? :)*

[image]

Thank your for suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried using `TTrayIcon.BalloonHint` ?

Comment: @ Warren P, edited, please see

Comment: -1 for vagueness. Analogue in what way? What's wrong with what you have? What *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, I just want a choice. It doesn't mean that if a component is good I don't want to have others. For me JEDI Desktop Alert is better than TMS, but may be some one can suggest something better than JEDI! I don't know all possible components in the world, so I'm asking :)

Comment: It's a better idea to say exactly what you want to do on StackOverflow. What does "good" mean to you? What does "choice" mean?  On stack overflow, nothing.   Instead, say you want it to have chocolate sprinkles, and wrapped in gold tinfoil. Whatever. But be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TMS Software has [TAdvAlertWindow](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advalert.asp), an *"Outlook 2003, 2007 style alert window"*.

[image: TAdvAlertWindow]

It's a commercial component, available separately or as part of the TMS Component Pack.

*Update:* The above image was taken from TMS website. As Andreas has pointed the font is not antialiased (it's a bitmapped font, probably MS Sans Serif). I've tested the trial version of the component and setting the font to Tahoma works as expected:

[image: TAdvAlertWindow antialiased]

Comment: I sincerely hope it can be used with a modern font compatible with ClearType.

Comment: @Andreas: you are right. I've used it time ago and I don't remember if it had font antialiasing, but I guess that it will support it with any TrueType/OpenType font.

Comment: For me JEDI Desktop Alert is better than TMS

Answer (score 4):

This might be a bit late, but below is a basic example of showing 5 stacked alert windows on top of each other in bottom right corner, using Jedi Desktop Alert.

[image: TJvDesktopAlertStack ScreenShot]

```
unit Unit1;


interface


uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls,
  JvDesktopAlert;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure AddAlert(title, text: String; stack: TjvDesktopAlertStack);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}  

procedure TForm1.AddAlert(title, text: String; stack: TjvDesktopAlertStack);
Begin
  with TJvDesktopAlert.Create(self) do
  Begin
    AutoFree   := true;
    AlertStack := stack;
    HeaderText := title;
    MessageText := text;
    Execute(self.Handle);
  End;
End;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  stack: TjvDesktopAlertStack;
begin
  stack := TJvDesktopAlertStack.Create(self);
  try
    AddAlert('title1', 'message1', stack);
    AddAlert('title2', 'message2', stack);
    AddAlert('title3', 'message3', stack);
    AddAlert('title4', 'message4', stack);
    AddAlert('title5', 'message5', stack);
  finally
    stack.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```